# Android change color cheched in CheckedTextView

Tags: android

Hi I want to change a color of CheckedTextView state but I can only chanhe color text . How I can do this? I do this :

```
 android:checkMark="@drawable/checked"
```

but it is a possible to change only color not all checkMark ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:checkMarkTint` attribute:

```
    <CheckedTextView
        android:checkMark="@drawable/..."
        android:checkMarkTint="@color/..."
```

[image]